# How to read a .txt file in Xcode 4 (iPhone App) correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, textview, text-files

I'm trying to read a .txt(test) file into a TextView (testText) :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
    if (filePath) {
        NSString *contentOfFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        testText.text = contentOfFile;
    }
    [filePath release];
}
```

Yes the file is in the Supporting Files directory.
I also tried some "similar" actions like "initWithContentOfFile" etc. but I got three different errors:
 1. SIGABRT
 2. EXEC_BAD_ACCESS
 3. It is reading the text but adds a lot of additional data it shouldn't display in the testText like {colortbl;red255 green 255 blue 255;margl1440.... and so on.

Am I doing it wrong? Well, certainly because it doesn't work, but at which part do I fail? The original text in the file is "This is a test. Finally it works!" its displayed too but only after a lot of strange additional text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't call `[filePath release];`. `-pathForResource:ofType:` will return an autoreleased string, so you shouldn't release it again.

The `{colortbl;red255...` text indicates that your file is actually an RTF file. It might be named `.txt`, but it is really RTF. You need to create a plain text file (in TextEdit you can choose Format > Make Plain Text to do this).

Comment: thanks =) I'm new to mac too so I didn't realize it was an .rtf
works fine now